# Eclipse plugin to mark code

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Is there an Eclipse plug-in to mark code, as with a highlighter pen. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could mark the line you want to highlight with a bookmark and then set a background color to highlight the bookmark.
You have to go in : `preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations` and then set the Text as highlighted with your preferred color :

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: +1 - I never paid any attention to Bookmarks before. There is actually a View that can be opened which will list out all of the Bookmarks placed so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such plug-in - I also searched Eclipse marketplace and Google for that.

However, if you have some experience with Eclipse plug-in development, writing an Eclipse command that creates an annotation for the selected text in the current editor should not be too hard (at least for your own use).

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `//TODO`. It gives a nice visual bookmark type thing which you can use to jump easily.