# How to mark code in eclipse as test code/untested/experimental/to fix/ incomplete?

Tags: java, eclipse

You could use comments to mark code. Besides that, is there a way to mark a block or line of code as experimental/only for test purposes ?

Pseudocode in java -

```
public SpecialObject importantMethod(){

System.out.println("Ready to go into if else"); // Test Code: Delete Later !

if(condition after a big series of method calls){

System.out.println("Entered into if"); // Test Code: Delete Later !

//execute code which is critical to program

}else
{

 System.out.println("Entered into else");  // Test Code: Delete Later !

 //execute code which is critical to program

}

 return specialObject;
}


public void anotherImportantMethod(){

 SpecialObject obj = importantMethod();

 //do something important with obj
}
```

Comment: You can use [task tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388292/how-do-i-enable-todo-fixme-xxx-task-tags-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example looks like this is what Log4j levels are required for. You can nominate different log levels for different categories (often corresponding to class names) and switch these on/off at deploy or runtime.

If your requirement isn't just restricted to logging, I would inject some component that you invoke suitable methods upon, and create different implementations (say, one called `TestExperimentalFunctionality` and one called `NoFunctionality`). They would both implement the same interface, and your core code wouldn't have to change. However you could provide differing implementations at deploy/runtime, thus giving you differing functionality.

Comment: Is log4j better than task tags mentioned by bmorris591 ?  My requirements are very simple.

Comment: Regardless of your requirements, I would investigate Log4j (or other logging frameworks) to allow you to manage your logfiles and logging requirements with a great deal of simplicity and flexibility

Answer (score 0):

First I want to add my own requirement that may interest you too, Then I will share my knowledge so far.

My requirement is that an indication like error will be shown on "Project Explorer" like a compilation error will. The use is so I won't accidentally commit, upload or publish a none complete or error code to air(That is not a compile error rather a business logic one).

Example:

I want it to show an error mark on project tree:
[This is like how compilation error will be marked at "Project Explorer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyUD3.png)

```
// SKIP this product
if(identifier==null){
// FIXME - REVERT THIS = TEST ONLY - Don't skip product
/*
  continue;
*/
}
```

For you:

1. There are bookmarks that you can use to highlight code. 
   See answer here:
   [Eclipse plugin to mark code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400007/eclipse-plugin-to-mark-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
2. There are "Task Tags" you can use to mark a comment in TODO, FIXME, XXX and customized. Window -> Preferences, and search for General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors -> Task tags, or for Java -> Compiler -> Task tags. See answear here: [IDE comment keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586478/ide-comment-keywords?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)